# WPF control set type as dependency property

Tags: wpf

Have some code:

```
<DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Rectangle Fill="Blue"></Rectangle>
          <TextBlock Text="test"></TextBlock>
     </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Instead of Rectangle i want to be able set any kind of shapes, like ellipse for example.

Want something like:

```
<DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Shape Fill="Blue" ShapeType={Binding DefaultShapeType}></Shape>
          <TextBlock Text="test"></TextBlock>
     </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well there are various ways. It depends a bit on the usage of the `DataTemplate`. Shall the type be provided by the VM? If so, normally the VM should not be aware of the view, assuming that you're using MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would usually use a [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and provide the [Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx) for its [Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data.aspx) property by a view model property:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Path Fill="Blue" Data="{Binding SomeGeometry}" />
        <TextBlock Text="test" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

There are a few basic geometries like LineGeometry, RectangleGeometry and EllipseGeometry, and also complex ones like StreamGeometry or PathGeometry, that enable you to draw virtually any kind of shape.

The specialized Shapes like Ellipse or Rectangle also use these Geometries to define their visual appearance.